# Want to play a list of sound files sequentially

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a set of `mid` type of files using `MediaPlayer`. But I am facing 2 problems with that.

**1)** I am not able to control the duration of each file being played. (There is a gap coming in between while playing the first and second `mid` file and so on).

**2)** I am not able to stop the loop of in between.(All the I have tried some workaround but that doesn't stop if a certain file is playing).

Here is my code:

```
private MediaPlayer player;
    private int[][] arohRagaTones = {{R.raw.s, R.raw.r1, R.raw.m1, R.raw.p, R.raw.d1, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r2_g1, R.raw.r3_g2, R.raw.m1, R.raw.d2_n1, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r2_g1, R.raw.r3_g2, R.raw.m1, R.raw.p, R.raw.d2_n1, R.raw.d3_n2, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r3_g2, R.raw.m1, R.raw.d1, R.raw.d3_n2, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r2_g1, R.raw.g3, R.raw.p, R.raw.d2_n1, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r1, R.raw.m1, R.raw.p, R.raw.d1, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r1, R.raw.r3_g2, R.raw.p, R.raw.d1, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r2_g1, R.raw.g3, R.raw.p, R.raw.n3, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r2_g1, R.raw.m1, R.raw.p, R.raw.d2_n1, R.raw.s},
            {R.raw.s, R.raw.r2_g1, R.raw.g3, R.raw.m1, R.raw.p, R.raw.d2_n1, R.raw.s}};

player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), arohRagaTones[musicPosition][currentArohTrack]);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(arohListener);
            player.start();

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener arohListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            if (currentArohTrack < arohRagaTones[musicPosition].length) {
                currentArohTrack++;
                try {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), arohRagaTones[musicPosition][currentArohTrack]);
                    Log.e(TAG, arohRagaTones[musicPosition][currentArohTrack] + "");
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(arohListener);
                    if (isRagaPlaying) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        pauseRaga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        playRaga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    pauseRaga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    playRaga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                pauseRaga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                playRaga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };
```

**All those `mid` files are small piano notes which has a duration of 1 second or 1.5 seconds. Please suggest How can I do a better implementation and solve those 2 major problems?**

Comment: First of all, **DO NOT** recreate MediaPlayer for each new file. Hope, it will solve all your problems. You may need to take a look into 3rd-party players, that don't require to recreate itself, for example BASS.

Comment: can you share the link of the library. @Miller

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/JochenHeizmann/monkeybass

Comment: There is no support for `MIDI` file type @Miller

Comment: It supports MIDI, http://www.un4seen.com/, search for BASSMIDI